# Hundreds of buttons in one page with same name and same ids, how to differentiate?

Tags: php, jquery, html, button

I have a problem here, I have a page with hundreds of products, each have "add to cart" button.
My problem is that all the buttons have same id and same name.
What I am doing here is when I want to click the button, the product name goes the the cart. But I don't think it will work as the ids and names are same.
Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Example of the code:

```
    <li class="ms-tt grid_3" data-id="id-1" data-type="digital">
                        <div class="m-thumb entry-image hover-content">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/jewellery-tools/casting-soldering1/14.jpg" alt='Flasks Stainless Steel Perforated C-16'></a>
                            <div class="image-overlay">
                                <div class="buttons-tt clearfix">
                                    <a class="permalink" href="#"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/jewellery-tools/casting-soldering1/14.jpg" data-gal="photo[portfolio]" title='Flasks Stainless Steel Perforated C-16'><i class="icon-resize-full"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="post-meta-ab"><span><a href="#">Flasks Stainless Steel Perforated C-16</a></span><br />
                        <span>Details: Flasks Stainless Steel Perforated For Casting 3" Dia X 5",6" & 7"</span><br />
                        <span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Shipping Weight: 750gms</span><br /><span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Price: &#8364; 17.00</span><br />
                        <span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Quantity: <input type="text" style="width:20px" maxlength="100" name="a1" id="a1" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Add" style="margin-top:-8px" class="btn btn-danger" name="asubmit" id="a1sub" /></span></p>
                    </li>
```

Please tell me how to solve the problem?

P.S is there any possible way to find which button is clicked? Can't I use $(this).clicked

Guerro's technique did the trick for me. Please see his answer below. Thanks

Comment: ID's **must** be unique!

Comment: What is creating these 100s of buttons? Can you output a unique product id with each one?

Comment: You should not use the same `ID` for multiple controls, that is not technically valid HTML. Plus it will make your life hell when trying to differentiate them as you are trying to now.

Comment: NEVER use the same **id**'s. Use **classes** when you want to attach an action or add style to a set of elements. The sole purpose of id's is to INDENTIFY a certain element.

Comment: Can't we detect in jquery which button was clicked?

Comment: Yes, via the button ID!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like Braziliam way, we call it as "Gambiarra"

```
$('input [type=submit]').click(function(){
   var productname = $(this).parent().find('.post-meta-ab a').html();
});
```

PS. If you cant set a UNIQUE ID for your DOM elements, don't use any at all.

Basically for each product on you list you have this structure:

```
<li class="ms-tt grid_3" data-id="id-1" data-type="digital">
                        <div class="m-thumb entry-image hover-content">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/jewellery-tools/casting-soldering1/14.jpg" alt='Flasks Stainless Steel Perforated C-16'></a>
                            <div class="image-overlay">
                                <div class="buttons-tt clearfix">
                                    <a class="permalink" href="#"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
                                    <a class="zoom" href="images/jewellery-tools/casting-soldering1/14.jpg" data-gal="photo[portfolio]" title='Flasks Stainless Steel Perforated C-16'><i class="icon-resize-full"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="post-meta-ab"><span><a href="#">Flasks Stainless Steel Perforated C-16</a></span><br />
                        <span>Details: Flasks Stainless Steel Perforated For Casting 3" Dia X 5",6" & 7"</span><br />
                        <span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Shipping Weight: 750gms</span><br /><span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Price: &#8364; 17.00</span><br />
                        <span><i class="icon-circle"></i>Quantity: <input type="text" style="width:20px" maxlength="100" name="a1" id="a1" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Add" style="margin-top:-8px" class="btn btn-danger" name="asubmit" id="a1sub" /></span></p>
                    </li>
```

Inside your `<li>` element you have your button and you have a `<p>` with your product title, and you `<p>` have a "post-meta-ab" class.
So when you say:

```
$('input [type=submit]').click(function(){ //here you'r saying, "when any input submit get clicked execute the code above"
   var productname = $(this).parent().find('.post-meta-ab a').html(); // here you are saying, $(this) means the input submit clicked, and parent() means your <li>, and finally you tell to look for any element with the post-meta-ab class and look for the a inside it.
});
```

Understand now?

Comment: Are you sure that "$('this')" is the clicked button?

Comment: If I follow the above syntax, then what will happen? $(this).parent().find('.post-meta-ab a').html(), so is there any chance to detect clicked button?

Comment: The follow syntax means, if any input of type submit is clicked, it'll get based on that clicked button positon the div with the class post-meta-ab(the one one the same div of the button), and get the HTML content of the <a> tag inside the "post-meta-ab" div class

Comment: So it will work or no? I want to confirm it, for some reason I think it may work irrespective of the same ids. Will it get the html of the same a?

Comment: I'll edit my answer explaining better w8 3 minutes and refresh

Comment: I understand the code above, I am asking whether it will work as the buttons have same name and ids. I think it should? as we are using "this".

Comment: If you'r asking it you doesn't understand the code. On this case we'r taking the button by the type, and (this) will means the button clicked, doesn't matter the id the name nothing. BUT THE GOOD PRATICES TELL YOU TO DON'T USE THE SAME ID. Just don't use any

Comment: Hey the on click button is returning null on click.